# Android - Adding layout into an existing layout programatically everytime button pressed

Tags: android-layout

I am building an app, where I have a plus button and every time the button is clicked a new layout with textboxes inside it is added.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:onClick="addAddbutton"
        android:text="add"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


mainActivity.java

package com.example.textboxonclick;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private LinearLayout ln;
private EditText myEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln);

}
public void addAddbutton(View v) {
    myEditText = new EditText(this);
    ln.addView(myEditText);
}
}
```